"New Opportunity" Lightening Quick Action Button Not Appearing on Contact Layout
I am trying to add the Salesforce standard "New Opportunity" button to the Contact Page Layout but it is still not visible. I have draggeed the button onto the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section and saved the layout. However, the button is not visible on the record page.
I am not sure what I could be doing wrong. Does anyone here know?
Thank you so much!



could it be this (recordTypes)? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383668&type=1

Do you have checked this?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388023&type=1
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007KIePKSA1


Add this button (New Opportunity) to "Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher" and give it a try it is working for me and is successfully showing and working in Contact Page Layout.



Here a couple of things for your to check:

Check if you are using Dynamic Action for the Highlight Panel, in Contact record page. Easiest way to find out, is edit the page and check the Highlights Panel. If yours look something like below, then you are using Dynamic Actions. Adding the Quick Action in Page Layout would not make it appear on the lightning record page. Instead you have to add it here, while editing the lighting-record page.


If you are not using Dynamic Action. Then, it could be due to Caching in Salesforce, which you can read more here.


